# How to scrape main headings of a website using python in colab?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-colaboratory

Hi I am a beginner and would like to get the list of all datasets from the website 'https://www.kaggle.com/datasets' based on the filters 'csv' and 'only datasets with tasks'.

I applied the filters and inspected the element. My attempt returns an empty list. This is my code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/datasets?sort=usability&fileType=csv&tasks=true'

html = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

titles = soup.find_all('li')
print(titles)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: first check in browser if you can access it when you are loged out. Some pages in kaggle need to login. And check if page works without JavaScript. `urllib` and `bs4` can't run `JavaScript` - and then you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`

Comment: first you could use `print( html )` to see what you get from server. It may send different HTML then you expect. Instead of `print()` you can save HTML in file and open in web browser to better see what you get.

Comment: I checked this portal needs JavaScript to add elements to HTML. It would be simpler to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for this.

Comment: using `DevTools` (tab `Network`, filter `XHR`) in Chrome/Firefox you can see all XHR/AJAX requests send to server and all responses. One of them sends all data as JSON which you can simply convert to python dictionary and you can get all information without BeautifulSoup. It needs `POST` requests with url https://www.kaggle.com/requests/SearchDatasetsRequest . It could be simpler with module `requests` instead of `urllib`. It may need all headers and cookies like in browser - so it is good to send GET to get fresh cookies.